# webclient.downloadfile not saving page completely

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I use following code to save a web page in my C# app, but page is not saved completely:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://jahanesanat.ir/currency.html", @"d://test/mytest66.html");
```

some parts of the page are not saved in the local file
What is going wrong?

Comment: Code looks fine. There probably problems with downloading or your expectations of "complete page" could be wrong (not looked at page/nor tried the code). Slightly more details would be useful.

Comment: this page contains some information that when I use webclient.Downloadfile its data are not saved completely, i.e. there are some parts in the page that are not visible in my saved file

Comment: "visible" as in what? Are you trying to open locally saved file in browser? Check text of the file - it should contain proper HTML closing tag... if not - see if tracing requests with Fiddler shows any interesting issues.

Comment: I'm guessing, the question is "how do you know, that some parts of the page are not saved?"

Comment: When I save page using browser save page, my page looks completely the same as its web version, but when I use webclient to save page (via code), page lacks some information (some parts of the html are not included in file)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe d://test/ is access denied

Use this sample from MSDN

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);        
Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + Application.StartupPath)
```